# D function using the x86 CMPXCHG Compare-and-swap

Tags: assembly, x86, d, cas

I'm looking for a function that presents a high level [D](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/1.0/) interface to an [atomic CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) on Intel x86.

I know I can do it with inline ASM (and if needed I will), but I'd rather just grab code from someone else if I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation at: http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/overview.html

> **Inline Assembler**
>
> Device drivers, high performance
>   system applications, embedded systems,
>   and specialized code sometimes need to
>   dip into assembly language to get the
>   job done. While D implementations are
>   not required to implement the inline
>   assembler, it is defined and part of
>   the language. Most assembly code needs
>   can be handled with it, obviating the
>   need for separate assemblers or DLL's.
>
> Many D implementations will also
>   support intrinsic functions
>   analogously to C's support of
>   intrinsics for I/O port manipulation,
>   direct access to special floating
>   point operations, etc.

So you could in theory use the CMPXCHG directly.

---

**Edit**

You may want look at: http://www.dsource.org/projects/tango/browser/trunk/tango/core/Atomic.d?rev=4277

It does take a while to load for some reason, but it is using the CMPXCHG instruction internally, it should be trivial to retool it for your purposes.

Comment: I know I can do it my self. I'm just wondering If I can just use something someone else has used.